# Codeception fails when popup is closed automatically

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I have a very simple acceptance test using Codeception and WebDriver. It tests signing in using Hybridauth ("login via.." *some social network).

The code:

```php
$I = $i = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Register using VK account (hybridauth) and check that friends list is loaded');

$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('VKontakte');

$I->click("VKontakte");

$__HANDLES= null;
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\WebDriver $webdriver) {
    GLOBAL $__HANDLES;
    $__HANDLES = $webdriver->getWindowHandles();
    $webdriver->switchTo()->window(end($__HANDLES));
}); // VK's popup loaded

codecept_debug($I->grabTextFrom('#install_allow'));

$I->seeElement('.box_login');

$I->fillField('email', '******');
$I->fillField('pass', '******');
$I->click($I->grabTextFrom('#install_allow'));

$I->dontSeeElement('.oauth_error');
```

*Each* line in this test is executed successfully, but at the end Codeception throws an exception complaining about "no window":

```html
[NoSuchWindowException]                                                                                                                            
  Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.                                                                                         
  Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'                                                                    
  System info: host: '***', ip: '***', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.7.0_65'  
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

The question is -- how to manage this situation to make test run smoothly? `$I->switchToWindow();` doesn't help.

*** UPDATE:
Resolved. The answer is simple: `$I->dontSeeElement('.oauth_error');` is fired when window is closed already. So we need to switch window first, and only then assert something.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The answer is simple: `$I->dontSeeElement('.oauth_error');` is fired when window is closed already. So we need to switch window first, and only then assert something.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem with OAuth2 Authentication.

We inject Javascript to give the Main window a known name, then we could switch the window after the PopUp disappear and the Webdriver lost his reference.

```
$I->executeJS('old_window_name = window.name; window.name="mainwindow"');
```

So this is the complete user step method to handle a PopUp login

```
public function openLoginPopup ()
{
    $I = $this;
    $I->amOnPage(\MainMenuPage::$URL);
    $I->doWait();

    $I->executeJS('old_window_name = window.name; window.name="mainwindow"');

    $I->click(\MainMenuPage::$loginButtonLocator);

    $I->switchToWindow(\LoginPage::$windowName);
}

public function fillLoginForm ($username, $password)
{
    $I = $this;
    $I->fillField('_username', $username);
    $I->fillField('_password', $password);
}

public function submitLoginData ()
{
    $I = $this;
    $I->click(\LoginPage::$loginButtonLocator);

    $I->switchToWindow('mainwindow');
    $I->executeJS('window.name=old_window_name');
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, everything was fine except the fact that I tried to operate with already-closed window (see the last line in the code). So I just got rid of that operation and instead switched to the main window.